# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class java.lang.Class has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase for my android app, and whenever I try to convert dataSnapshot to object I get the following error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class java.lang.Class has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead
```

Here is my class:

```
class DatabaseApi<T> {

    suspend fun getData(path: String): DatabaseResult<Class<T>?> {
        val databaseResult = DatabaseHelper().get(path)

        return try {
            convertDatabaseSnapshot(databaseResult.value)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            DatabaseResult.failed(e.toString())
        }
    }

    fun <T> convert(cls: Class<T>, snapShot: DataSnapshot): DatabaseResult<T?> {
        return try {

            val data = snapShot.getValue(cls)
            DatabaseResult.success(data)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            val message = e.message ?: ""
            DatabaseResult.failed(message)
        }
    }

    inline fun <reified T> convertDatabaseSnapshot(snapShot: DataSnapshot): DatabaseResult<T?> {
        return convert(T::class.java, snapShot)
    } 
}
```

And this is the code where I am getting the error:

```
val data = snapShot.getValue(cls)
```

Comment: What exactly is the `cls` that you're passing to `convert()`, eventually going to `getValue()`? That's the problem.

Comment: here T is my dataClass and im trying to convert dataSnapshot into T i.e dataClass

Comment: So, what is the actual class `cls` that you're passing? What specifically should this function return given an `cls` and snapshot at runtime? Please be specific.  What you have right now is too abstract.  You will want to edit the question to show the class that you're passing, the contents of the snapshot, and what you expect the function to return.

Comment: in this case my T is 'User.kt', if i directly use T i.e ```val user = snapShot.getValue(T::class.java)``` then i'm getting following error: ```cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. use a class instead```